# How to write a good report with LateX

Tags: report

this is my first post on tex exchange , i am using latex for the first time for my internship report .
I read that lateX is very useful and professionnal especially for writing equation .
I've found a lot of Books about it but i'm not fan of them ... i was wondering if there is a method , steps or structure to follow to make a good report

thanks

Comment: @Werner yes i have found the post useful , i  want just to know brievely what the best way to make a good report beause on books we found only the syntax of how to use latex

Comment: "What is the best way to make a good report..." may solicit primarily opinion-based answers, or somewhat subjective ones in nature. It's far better to have something already written that you ask questions about.

Comment: @Werner so you suggest that i start writing the report and finally post it so to know if there will be some improvement on it right ?

Comment: Yes. Don't post your *entire* report though. Instead, focus on small parts that might need help. Again, don't request "how can I make this better" without showing stuff that you've tried. Otherwise it may just request subjective answers.

Comment: thanks , i have already go into troubles especially with special caracters and math equations but  I've found most of the solutions here